# Caesars cypher issue

Tags: c

I am having trouble with getting this to work I need pointed in the right direction. The user will input a command line integer to determine how many places the characters will be rotated.  My problem is that I want all lower case and upper case to stay the same case along with keeping spaces and special characters untouched, only rotating the letters by the specified integer. I need to make sure that for example: the integer set is 1 and the character "Z" is entered in the string to be encrypted it needs to wrap back around to "A" instead of going to the next ASCII character "[" I have been trying to use the "%" operator but I might be using it wrong. I am not looking for someone to write the entire code for me and I know I could find my answer by looking at the source code of a working program but I am trying to figure as much of this out by myself but right now I am stumped and need a small bit of help. Thanks!

I finally got it to work I had the entire operation wrong this is what worked for me.

```
char encrypt = ('A' + ( ( (input[i] - 'A') + key ) % 26));
```

Before I was trying

```
char encrypt (input[i] + key) % 26;
```

Thanks for the fast answers!

Comment: Use modulo (`%`) operation to make shift cyclic and use `if` to handle special cases

Comment: If you don't want people to write your code for you, I would recommend showing what you have tried and demonstrating how it has not worked. Can you paste in what you've tried so far? Explain where you've gotten stuck?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While there are many ways to accomplish what you want, I suggest that you look into `java.util.Map`.  Decide if this is an encryption `Map` or a decryption `Map` and "put" the *input* character as the key, and the output character as the value.  Then when you need to translate, you simply walk through each to-be-translated character and assemble the output value.  Pay attention to unmapped values (as they will return null upon lookup).